# Understanding MongoDb runtimeStats object got as a result of enabling "recordQueryStats : true"

Tags: mongodb, profiling

I am using nodejs-mongoDb version 1.3.19 with nodeJs. To get query stats I've set `recordQueryStats:true` now I get something like this :

```
{ queryStats:

   { m_n: 22,
     m_oldM: 666.9545454545455,
     m_oldS: 45735878.95454546,
     m_newM: 666.9545454545455,
     m_newS: 45735878.95454546,
     numDataValues: [Getter],
     mean: [Getter],
     variance: [Getter],
     standardDeviation: [Getter],
     sScore: [Getter] }
}
```

As I'm new to this, can anyone explain what do these fields resemble?

Comment: 1.3.19 is the node.js MongoDB driver version right? It is not likely to be the database version.

Answer (score 0):

The queryStats object contains request latency statistics. The m_* values are used to calculate the statistics provided via the "Getter" functions. The following blog entry provides more background on these stats: http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html

Within the driver the a new data point is [recorded here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/61aea0488a219be783daf54b13c2c95f0dfa79b5/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js#L474).